# sqlite transform tree table (hierarchical) into a flat one

Tags: sqlite, hierarchical-data

I'm quite stuck with this problem here and will highly appreciate any help. 
I need to transform a tree table / hierarchical like this:

```
id    name    parent
 1     aaa          
 2     bbb         1
 3     ccc         1
 4     ddd         2
 5     eee         2
 6     fff         5
```

Where
id - is a unique identifier
parent - is the id of a parent item to which a given record relates

The above table needs to get transformed from a deep hierarchy into a flat horizontal table like the one below, where `parent` column is flattened and spread across multiple columns which show hierarchy from left to right:

```
parent  descendent_1  descendent_2   descendent_n+1     id    name   
  null          null          null              ...      1     aaa                 
     1          null          null              ...      2     bbb                
     1          null          null              ...      3     ccc         
     1             2          null              ...      4     ddd         
     1             2          null              ...      5     eee         
     1             2             5              ...      6     fff
```

The deepness may vary from record to record.
Here is an example of a data set:

```
CREATE TABLE table_1 (id int, name text, parent int);

INSERT INTO table_1 VALUES
(1,'aaa',null),
(2,'bbb',1),
(3,'ccc',1),
(4,'ddd',2),
(5,'eee',2),
(6,'fff',5),
(7,'ggg',6),
(8,'hhh',7),
(9,'iii',3),
(10,'jjj',3),
(11,'kkk',8),
(12,'lll',11);
```

Thanks a million!

Comment: Use recursive-cte

Comment: @KamilG. I kind of get what you mean but I can't get my head around how do I go about adding unknown number of columns with a recursive cte?

Comment: That would require a procedure with dynamic SQL statement build within a string to add columns. More complicated thing.

Comment: Please provide something of an [mcve], i.e. a tailored toy database with sample data. To do that either use the `.dump` feature or list a few lines of `create .. ` and `insert ...`. Also please explain your desired output. I see three identically headlined colums "id". Which is which?

Comment: @Yunnosch I edited column names. What I need is to go from deep to flat horizontal structure without knowing the deepness. As KamilG. notices I need to go recursion but this is where I'm stuck.

Comment: How about providing an explanation of the meaning of the ids. Wildly guessing I'd say that they are something like parent id, left child id right child id and own id. The easiest way of getting your desired output is just printing it. But that is not what you want. In order to get what you want you need to explain more about the logic behind.

Comment: Please provide a toy database as MCVE.

Comment: @Yunnosch sorry for confusion. I've edited my question. The database is absolutely same as in example. There is a unique id, name and parent column which establishes parent -> child relationship.

Comment: Please provide something of an Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example, i.e. a tailored toy database with sample data. To do that either use the `.dump` feature or list a few lines of `create ...` and `insert ...`. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Yunnosch didn't quite get it at first time! I've added a sample with create and insert statements. Thanks!

Comment: I do not get the logic of your desired output. Line has name "bbb" with its own id 2 and a parent id of 1 (which refers to "aaa"). That I get. But I wonder why the descendent_1 is "null", which I take to mean "has not even one decendent". This contrasts with the line from the table `4     ddd         2`, which I understand to indicate that the parent of "ddd" has id 2, which means "bbb". So you see, without explanation of your desired output, I cannot help you. Could you provide some rendundant sentences, like "the null in line column 2 of line 2 means ..."?

Comment: @Yunnosch Yes, it is a bit confusing. `"aaa"` is the parent for all items. Line `4 ddd 2` has a parent `2 bbb 1` which in turn is a child of `1 aaa 0`. For example `1 -> 3 -> 9` so the deepness of this relation is 2 if we assume `1` is on zero level as it is the parent for all items. 
Whereas `1 -> 2 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 11` relation has deepness of 5, at that `2` bifurcates and has another relation:
`1 -> 2 -> 4` and here the deepness is 2.

So the output needs to be flat horizontal which goes from left to right, the way I described relations above, where each field is for parent/descendant.

Comment: If bbb is child of aaa, why does desired output show null for all descendants of aaa? Why has desired output a line with name ddd, which seems to also show that bbb is child of aaa, but no more information on ddd? Please, please write one sentence of explanation for at least each kind of entry in the desired output table.

Comment: Hmmm. Could I describe the meaning of the columns as "most remote parent" (which might also be the closest parent, if there is only one level of parents), "second-most remote parent" (closer by one than the most remote parent), "third-most remote parent" (one closer than second most, two closer than most remote)? That would make sense to me. If yes, then I realise I was confused by the column heads saying "descendant", while to me they are actually all parents/ancestors.

Comment: @Yunnosch yes it's absolutely right! Remoteness decreases from `left to right`.